# How do I "continue" in a `Monad` loop?

Tags: haskell

Often times I found myself in need of skipping the rest of the *iteration* (like `continue` in C) in Haskell:

```
forM_ [1..100] $ \ i ->
    a <- doSomeIO
    when (not $ isValid1 a) <skip_rest_of_the_iteration>
    b <- doSomeOtherIO a
    when (not $ isValid2 b) <skip_rest_of_the_iteration>
    ...
```

However, I failed to find an easy way to do so. The only way I am aware of is probably the `Trans.Maybe`, but is it necessary to use a monad transform to achieve something so trivial?

Comment: There are a few packages on Hackage offering loops of various sorts. The most interesting I've seen is probably https://hackage.haskell.org/package/loops

Comment: Monad transformers are never necessary -- merely convenient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remember that loops like this in Haskell are not magic...they're just normal first-class things that you can write yourself.

For what it's worth, I don't think it's too useful to think of `MaybeT` as a Monad transformer.  To me, `MaybeT` is just a newtype wrapper to give an alternative implementation of `(>>=)`...just like how you use `Product`, `Sum`, `First`, `And`, etc. to give alternative implementations of `mappend` and `mempty`.

Right now, `(>>=)` for you is `IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b`.  But it'd be more useful to have `(>>=)` here be `IO (Maybe a) -> (a -> IO (Maybe b) -> IO (Maybe b)`.  As soon as you get to the first action that returns a `Nothing`, it's really impossible to "bind" any further.  That's exactly what `MaybeT` gives you.  You also get a "custom instance" of `guard`, `guard :: Bool -> IO (Maybe a)`, instead of `guard :: IO a`.

```
forM_ [1..100] $ \i -> runMaybeT $ do
  a <- lift doSomeIO
  guard (isValid1 a)
  b <- lift $ doSomeOtherIO a
  guard (isValid2 b)
  ...
```

and that's it :)

`MaybeT` is not magic either, and you can achieve basically the same effect by using nested `when`s.  It's *not necessary*, it just makes things a lot simpler and cleaner :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. However, maybe I didn't make it clear (I'm editing my question), but what I wanted is not a `break` but a `continue`. There's a subtle difference --- I would like to skip the rest of the *iteration*, not the entire loop. I have changed the question.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you would do it using bare-bones recursion:

```
loop [] = return ()   -- done with the loop
loop (x:xs) =
  do a <- doSomeIO
     if ...a...
        then return ()  -- exit the loop
        else do -- continuing with the loop
                b <- doSomeMoreIO
                if ...b...
                   then return () -- exit the loop
                   else do -- continuing with the loop
                           ...
                           loop xs -- perform the next iteration
```

and then invoke it with:

```
loop [1..100]
```

You can tidy this up a bit with the `when` function from Control.Monad:

```
    loop [] = return ()
    loop (x:xs) =
      do a <- doSomeIO
         when (not ...a...) $ do
           b <- doSomeMoreIO
           when (not ...b...) $ do
             ...
             loop xs
```

There is also `unless` in Control.Monad which you might prefer to use.

Using @Ørjan Johansen 's helpful advice, here is an simple example:

```
import Control.Monad

loop [] = return ()
loop (x:xs) = do
  putStrLn $ "x = " ++ show x
  a <- getLine
  when (a /= "stop") $ do
  b <- getLine
  when (b /= "stop") $ do
  print $ "iteration: " ++ show x ++ ": a = " ++ a ++ " b = " ++ b
  loop xs

main = loop [1..3]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop over a list or other container to perform actions and/or produce a summary value, and you're finding the usual convenience tools like `for_` and `foldM` aren't good enough for the job, you might want to consider `foldr`, which is plenty strong enough for the job. When you're not really looping over a container, you can use plain old recursion or pull in something like `https://hackage.haskell.org/package/loops` or (for a very different flavor) `https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines` or perhaps `https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying out `loops`, but I couldn't get `break_` to work. Can you have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918416/how-do-i-use-break-in-the-package-loops)?