# How do I use `break_` in the package "loops"?

Tags: loops, haskell, break

Looking into the package [`loops`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/loops-0.2.0.2), I found it very interesting and could be useful. However, there's one part about the package that I don't understand: how am I supposed to use [`break_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/loops-0.2.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Loop.html#v:break_)?

Let's say I have a function `get' :: IO (Maybe Int)`, with which each call will return a number read from a file, and returns `Nothing` if the EOF is reached. I'm trying to construct a simple loop where I print each number and break upon EOF.

Now, I know to loop indefinitely I can use `forever`:

```
import Control.Monad.Loop as ML
import Control.Monad as M

main = do
    M.sequence . loop $ do
        ML.forever
        return $ do
            mx <- get'
            case mx of
                Nothing -> ???
                Just x  -> print x
```

But where do I put my `break_`? It is a `LoopT IO Int`, so I can only put it in `LoopT` monad, but isn't it supposed to be called mid interation, instead of when defining loops? This really confuses me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LoopT` is a monad transfomer, so you will need to `liftIO` your `print x` statement.

Here are some usage examples:

```
import Control.Monad 
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Loop as ML

-- infinite printing loop
foo :: LoopT IO ()
foo = do
  x <- ML.iterate 0 (+1) 
  liftIO $ print x

run_foo = ML.exec_ foo

-- prints 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
bar :: IO () 
bar = ML.exec_ $ do
  x <- ML.iterate 1 (+2)
  if x < 10
    then liftIO $ print x
    else break_
```

**Update**

If you want to execute a infinite loop in another monad, I would just use `forever` from `Control.Monad` --

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State

myloop = forever $ do
  x <- get
  liftIO $ print x
  put (x+1)

main = runStateT myloop 10 -- start loop at 10
```

**Update 2**

Another example using a monadic condition:

```
findFavoriteNumber = ML.exec_ $ do
  x <- ML.iterate 1 (+1)
  yn <- liftIO $ do putStr $ "is " ++ show x ++ " your favorite number? "
                    getLine
  if yn == "yes"
    then break_
    else return ()
```

Of course, this loop doesn't return the favorite number - it just keeps asking until the user responds with "yes".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the loop you provided is stopped using a constant. What if the stop condition is dynamically detected like the example I provided?

Comment: Just replace the condition in the if statement with whatever boolean expression you want.

Comment: Thanks. But what if that `if` condition itself is an `IO` monad, as it is in my example? I can't just say `if isNothing get' then ...`.

Comment: I just added another example with a monadic condition.

Comment: Ahhh ... now I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a direct translation of your loop to `loops` style:

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad.Loop as ML
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Control.Exception
import System.IO.Error
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

get' :: IO (Maybe Int)
get' = do
  catchJust (\e -> if isEOFError e then Just () else Nothing)
            (return . readMaybe =<< getLine)
            (const $ return Nothing)

main :: IO ()
main = exec_ $
  ML.forever >> do
    mx <- liftIO get'
    case mx of
      Nothing -> break_
      Just x -> liftIO (print x)
```

Comment: Thank you for going extra miles. Previously I didn't realize that I was supposed to put my iteration content in the same `do`-statement as the iterators (as oppose to putting them in the last `return`).

Comment: @trVoldemort, it's admittedly a somewhat peculiar interface.